# How to calculate the context-situation similarity in context-aware recommender system

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I am new to python and to the field of recommendation systems. I read that i can use cosine similarity from surprise library to compute the similarity between two users or two items based on rating data. I want to calclate similarities between contexts of users or items, How to do that? can i use the same cosine similarity method and give the context value instead of reating value??